# Use variable in Terraform remote backend

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-remote-state

```
# Using a single workspace:
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "company"

    workspaces {
      name = "my-app-prod"
    }
  }
}
```

For Terraform remote backend, would there be a way to use variable to specify the organization / workspace name instead of the hardcoded values there?

The [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/remote.html)
didn't seem to mention anything related either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [backend configuration documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html) goes into this in some detail. The main point to note is this:

> Only one backend may be specified and the configuration **may not contain interpolations**. Terraform will validate this.

If you want to make this easily configurable then you can use [partial configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration) for the static parts (eg the type of backend such as S3) and then provide config at run time interactively, via environment variables or via command line flags.

I personally wrap Terraform actions in a small shell script that runs `terraform init` with command line flags that uses an appropriate S3 bucket (eg a different one for each project and AWS account) and makes sure the state file location matches the path to the directory I am working on.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems and was very disappointed with the need of additional init/wrapper scripts. Some time ago I started to use Terragrunt.

It's worth taking a look at Terragrunt because it closes the gap between Terraform and the lack of using variables at some points, e.g. for the remote backend configuration:
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/#keep-your-backend-configuration-dry