# terraform backend input variables

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use terraform scripts that could generate multiple instances of infra having different states and variables . Currently i am testing if this is possible using terraform backend with local . 
Eventually we plan to move to azure vault to store multiple terraform states

I am aware that backend doest have variable support. But is there anyway i could pass the path variable to terraform init ?

```
    *terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "./states/"${local.prefix}state.tfstate"
  }
}*
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63314695/790879

Answer (score 1):

Currently we are using [Kapitan](https://github.com/deepmind/kapitan) for handling such scenarios.

Essentially you have an inventory with all valuable parameters, keeping the TF modules in a `/components` directory ( basically your templates ). During `kapitan compile` all replacement would happen and your ready for execution TF code with proper variable replacement would be stored in `/compiled`.

This gives you the flexibility to also modify on run K8s manifests, basic scripts ...