# terraform interpolation with variables returning error

Tags: terraform

I am trying to add variables in string

```
# variables.tf file
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
      bucket    = terraform-20200527"
      workspace_key_prefix  = "customer"
      key   =  "env/${env_name}/terraform.tfstate"
      region = "us-east-1"
      profile   = "default"
  }
}
```

getting error:

```
Error: Variables not allowed

   on variables.tf line 7, in terraform:
       7:     key   =  "env/${env_name}/terraform.tfstate"

Variables may not be used here.
```

Comment: You can't use variables when configuring backends. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831460/2291321 might be useful for you.